# Shield encryption on long text that stores JSON

Tags: platform-encryption

I have to store json data in long text fields and I have to encrypt said fields with Salesforce Shield. I've heard that data clipping might occur in this case.
Is this true? I couldn't find any doc regarding json encryption.

Comment: Do you use any not ASCII characters in those JSON? If not, then there should be no problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This knowledge article suggests](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_custom_fields.htm&type=5) that you can easily encrypt Long Text Area fields.

> **Which Custom Fields Can I Encrypt?**
>
> You can encrypt the contents of fields that belong to one these custom field types, on either standard
> or custom objects.
>
> - Email
> - Phone
> - Text
> - Text Area
> - Text Area (Long)
> - URL
> - Date
> - Date/Time
>
> After a custom field is encrypted, you can’t change the field type.
> For custom phone and email fields, you also can’t change the field
> format.

Also, about ASCII characters.

> **Field Limits with Shield Platform Encryption**
>
> Under certain conditions, encrypting a field can impose limits on the
> values that you store in that field. Before deciding to encrypt a
> field, make sure that you know these limits.
>
> **Custom Fields**
>
> If you expect users to enter non-ASCII values, such as CJK-encoded
> data, we recommend creating validation rules to enforce these limits:
>
> - Email custom field type values that contain only non-ASCII characters are limited to 70 characters.
> - Phone custom field type values that contain only non-ASCII characters are limited to 22 characters.
>
> **Body Field on the Case Comment Object**
>
> The Body field on the Case Comment object has a limit of 4,000 ASCII
> characters (or 4,000 bytes). However, when these fields are encrypted,
> the character limit is lower. How much lower depends on the kind of
> characters you enter.
>
> - ASCII—2959
> - Chinese, Japanese, Korean—1333
> - Other non-ASCII—1479
>
> Name Fields on the Contact Object
>
> When Shield Platform Encryption is enabled for the Name field on the
> Contact object, the character limit is lower for First and Last Name
> fields for some character types. Shield Platform Encryption doesn’t
> affect ASCII character limits.
>
> - First Name—22 non-ASCII character limit
> - Last Name—70 non-ASCII character limit

Also, other limitations.

> **General Shield Platform Encryption Considerations**
>
> These considerations apply to all data that you encrypt using Shield
> Platform Encryption.
>
> **Custom Fields**
>
> You can’t use encrypted custom fields in custom formula fields or
> criteria-based sharing rules. Some custom fields can’t be encrypted:
>
> - Fields that have the Unique or External ID attributes or include these attributes on previously encrypted custom fields
> - Fields that are used in custom formula fields
> - Fields on external data objects
> - Fields that are used in an account contact relation
>
> You can’t use Schema Builder to create an encrypted custom field.
>
> **SOQL/SOSL**
>
> - Encrypted fields can’t be used with the following SOQL and SOSL clauses and functions: – Aggregate functions such as MAX(), MIN(), and
>   COUNT_DISTINCT() – WHERE clause – GROUP BY clause – ORDER BY clause
>   Tip: Consider whether you can replace a WHERE clause in a SOQL query
>   with a FIND query in SOSL.
> - When you query encrypted data, invalid strings return an INVALID_FIELD error instead of the expected MALFORMED_QUERY.